# Javascript/ES6 default parameter values

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I recently received control over a node backend and I am not really familiar with node / javascript / es6 and here is the situation:

a function that sets a default value in the parameter, like say:

```
function multiply (a, b = 2) {
   return a * b;
}
```

works as expected on my local machine when testing, but on the server it gets an unexpected token error.

As far as I can tell everything on both the local machine and the server are in parity with their configuration.

I must be missing something small.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Node version 8.1.3 if that is at all helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't have any issue with 8.1.3... are you sure that's the server version, or just the node version on your local machine?

Comment: If you want to be certain, you can [`console.log(process.version);`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version)

Comment: Did you mean "parity" instead of "parody"? Though that sounds weird either, I guess (not a native speaker) the proper term would be "in unison".

Comment: It sure sounds like you're running an older version of nodejs on the server that does not yet support default parameters.  You need to verify the nodejs version on the server.

Comment: @Bergi yes haha

Comment: @jfriend00 I have verified the version on the server as 8.1.3, because I had updated it specifically to match my local version

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If you want to post that as an answer, you should.  Even though everything was updated on the server, it looks like after updating node, the process doing the execution of our server code was never restarted so it was still running an old version of node.  Version 4.4.3